# How can I style an MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, user-interface, styles, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

I'm adding the items programatically, but MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem doesn't seem to offer any way to style it to fit in with a BlackTranslucent UIToolBar...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` is a subclass of `UIBarButtonItem` which has a `tintColor` property. You can use this to make your button black.

```
MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *userTrackingBarButtonItem = 
        [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView];

[self.navigationController.toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
[userTrackingBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

If you do set it to black like this, the user will never know when it's activated, as the blue color is never shown.

[image: black button]